# Iterating through method call of a collection of instantiated classes

Tags: java, iteration, abstract

```
abstract class NodekaClass {
    abstract HashMap getBuffs();
    abstract void setBuffs(HashMap<String, Boolean> buffs);   
}

class Barbarian extends NodekaClass {

    public HashMap <String, Boolean> buffs;

    @Override
    public HashMap getBuffs() {
        return this.buffs;
    }
}
```

Now for the issue.. if I try to do this:

```
        for (NodekaClass pet : activePets) {
            for (String s : pet.getBuffs().keySet()) {

            }
        }
```

It says I need to cast s as a generic object and won't let me access any of the String methods obviously.

I could do a typecast like this...

```
       for (NodekaClass pet : activePets) {
            for (Object o : pet.getBuffs().keySet()) {
                if ("Test".equals((String) o))
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

But this is clunky. Is there a better way to iterate in this situation?

Comment: What do you expect to have in your HashMap ? The Key will always be a String? What do you expect as values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `public HashMap getBuffs()` to `public HashMap<String, Boolean> getBuffs()`

As written your method is returning a plain `HashMap` and want to return a generic version, one with the generic declaration in place. Understand that generics are for the compiler only and not for the JVM where they almost don't exist, and so if your method is not declare to return it, the compiler will only know that the method returns a plain HashMap.

Comment: Okay so am I returning the generic "HashMap" and not my specific container?

Comment: @IsaacCroas: You are returning a plain `HashMap` and want to return a generic version, one with the generic declaration in place. Understand that generics are for the compiler only and not for the JVM where they almost don't exist, and so if your method is not declare to return it, the compiler will only know that the method returns a plain HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it this way:

```
@Override
public HashMap<String,Boolean> getBuffs() {
    return this.buffs;
}
```

Then your first way would work without pain.

Answer (score 0):

Use Generics https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ to avoid typecasting at runtime in collections.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to cast: the `equals()` method accepts parameters of type `Object`, so this test:

```
if ("Test".equals(o))
```

Will work correctly and safely, ie it will be `true` if `o` is a String `"Test"` (`false` otherwise) and won't throw any exceptions no matter what class `o` is (including `null`).

Answer (score 0):

If your map key are Strings and values are Booleans you can delare it like that:

```
abstract class NodekaClass {
abstract Map<String, Boolean> getBuffs();
abstract void setBuffs(Map<String, Boolean> buffs);
```

}

```
class Barbarian extends NodekaClass {

public Map<String, Boolean> buffs;

@Override
public Map<String, Boolean>getBuffs() {
    return this.buffs;
}
```